# How does Visual Studio extension pack extension versioning work?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

When creating an extension pack for Visual Studio, does the `vsixId` refer to a package or a specific version of a package?

For example, if you were to follow [Walkthrough: Create an Extension Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthough-create-extension-pack?view=vs-2019&source=docs), when a user installs the extension pack, will the latest version of each extension always be installed, or will potentially old versions of the extensions be installed?

Example `.vsext` from the walkthrough which shows how the `vsixId` is referenced.

```
{
 "id": "ExtensionPack1",
 "name": "ExtensionPack1",
 "description": "Read about creating extension packs at https://aka.ms/vsextpack",
 "version": "1.0.0.0",
 "extensions": [  // List of extensions that are included in the Extension Pack.
   {
     "vsixId": "41858b2d-ff0b-4a43-80b0-f1b2d6084935",
     "name": "AlignAssignments"
   },
   {
     "vsixId": "42374550-426a-400e-96f9-237682e8dea6",
     "name": "CopyAsHtml"
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vsixId` means the id of the latest available extension package from the **Visual Studio Marketplace**.

**Actually**, `Visual Studio Marketplace` only obtains the latest VS extension package.

**And** the old versions of the vs extensions cannot be got on **Visual Studio Marketplace**,so it will not install the old previous versions of the extensions.

When you use `vsixid` in `Extension Pack`, it automatically gets the corresponding extension package available from the Visual Studio Marketplace. **In other words**, the value of the `vsixid` means the only available latest extension package.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation